# Pandas dataframe: Grouping columns having the same first characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
                            LIT__0001   LIT__002    AAA__0001   AAA__0002   XYZ
2019-10-31 13:40:00-04:00   NaN         0.014786    10          55          1
2019-10-31 13:45:00-04:00   NaN         0.012143    33          11          2
2019-10-31 13:50:00-04:00   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         3
2019-10-31 13:55:00-04:00   NaN         0.020000    14          13          4
2019-10-31 14:00:00-04:00   0.010000    NaN         14          NaN         5
```

I need to convert it to a dataframe like the following

```
                            LIT         AAA         XYZ
2019-10-31 13:40:00-04:00   0.014786    10          1
2019-10-31 13:45:00-04:00   0.012143    11          2
2019-10-31 13:50:00-04:00   NaN         NaN         3
2019-10-31 13:55:00-04:00   0.020000    13          4
2019-10-31 14:00:00-04:00   0.010000    14          5
```

That is, for every column having common first characters before '__', take the minimun for each row.

My dataframe is really huge so I would apreciate the faster solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) by columns with `axis=1` and lambda function for split:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('__')[0], axis=1, sort=False).min()
```

Or use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('__').str[0], axis=1, sort=False).min()
print (df)
                                LIT   AAA  XYZ
2019-10-31 13:40:00-04:00  0.014786  10.0  1.0
2019-10-31 13:45:00-04:00  0.012143  11.0  2.0
2019-10-31 13:50:00-04:00       NaN   NaN  3.0
2019-10-31 13:55:00-04:00  0.020000  13.0  4.0
2019-10-31 14:00:00-04:00  0.010000  14.0  5.0
```